# Web application, permission based menus (disabled vs invisible)

Tags: php, web-applications, user-interface, user-controls

I have developed several permission based web applications that simply eliminate menu and other options based upon the current users permissions or role. I'm considering disabling these options as opposed to eliminating them on my newest project. This will allow the option to be there but unavailable. I can see where this would be a better approach in app documentation (help, etc.) but can also see where it could be worse. I'm looking for some guidance from those who have used both methods.

Comment: I think that depends on what kind of end-users / line of business are using your applications.

Comment: The two issues I see are 1. security, and 2. presentation.  1. How much do you trust your users? In other words, do you want users to be able to see what they can't do - and therefore give them the opportunity to try to trick their way into those features?  2. How will it look to the user with the least permissions?  Will there be disabled links/buttons all over the place?  This could make it much harder to use.

Comment: What are the two methods that you are referring to? Disabling or eliminating permission control feature?

Comment: @kidonchu Those are the two methods; Either disable or not have it available in the first place. All depending upon what group or role the current user. I'm leaning toward the latter. Most of my work is for corporations, and my customer base has grown in terms of corporate size and number of users. As a result, there are more roles that have nothing to do with each other (e.g., accounting and maintenance) in terms of user interface options.